# Minimizing the sum of a product

Tags: calculus

I am having a hard time coming up with a function to represent a word problem.

The product of three values equals 192. one of the values is twice another. What is the minimum value of their sum. Given all three values are greater than 0.

So far I have came up with:

$ABC=192$

$A=2B$

$2BBC=192$

$2B^2C=192$

However after this point I am stuck as to  what I need to express to get a representation of a function. I assume the function needs to be broken down into a coefficient, but I am not certian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use $x,y$, and $z$ for the three quantities. We have $xyz=192$, and $y=2x$, so $2x^2z=192$, or $x^2z=96$. We want to minimize $x+y+z$, given that $x,y,z>0$. Now $$x+y+z=3x+z=3x+\frac{96}{x^2}\;,$$ so we have enough information to express the sum in terms of $x$ alone. It’s now a straightforward calculus problem.

Comment: Where did you get your $3x+z$  from?

Comment: @Bob: $y=2x$, so $x+y=3x$.